# Used commercial aircraft engines

Tags: faa-regulations, commercial-aviation, engine

We are a scrap company and have experience with dismantling and scraping old commercial airplanes. Now we got an offer to receive an aircraft for its last landing, with engines, etc...I assume that engines are not possible to re-sell and they just want everything to be scrapped? any tips?

Comment: Who is "they"? Do "they" owned the engines, or had leased them to the engine manufacturer?

Comment: What type of aircraft are we talking about?

Comment: When you say you are a scrap company does that mean you are just really interested in harvesting the metal, etc. rather than recovering avionics, etc.? Reselling aviation parts is an involved process since all things aviation are tightly regulated. There are companies that operate solely as "aviation junkyards" that resell used parts. If the owner is contacting a scrap company they probably believe there are no useful parts, otherwise they would probably contact a company like Dodson that buys aircraft to resell parts.

Comment: we are waiting for more info on the type of the aircraft, but they are from 80 to 150 seats aircraft.

Comment: I dont know why they are deleting my comments/questions. I thought this forum is broad minded, but than I see that my question is marked as "not aviation related", than what? I have to explain certain things before asking a question, and when I ask a question, people ask me about more info, and I post more info in a manner of comment and a question. If you people are so strict, than I will go somewhere else and discuss without pressure.

Answer (score 1):

They will have some value if you also receive the aircraft maintenance logs.  Components are virtually useless without a way to trace age, time, past service/repairs, and compliance with any service bulletins (SB) or airworthiness directices (AD).

Comment: we dont know at the moment, we just got in inquiry, mostly they are interested in licencing and documentation for dismantling for which we have.